# Why is it at times impossible to get an answer?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I've posted a problem twice, asking for help, and I've yet to have anyone respond? What gives?

Comment: Patience is a virtue.

Comment: How many questions have you answered?

Comment: @GregS: I don't think the number of answered question should be a factor in whether someone should receive help or not. Unless, of course, you're referring to accept rate. If responding to questions was based on how number of answers given by the user - newbies would never get any help!

Comment: @Saladin Akara: Neither one. I just think one should be aware that answering questions can be difficult. If one hasn't answered any  then one should understand that.

Comment: @GregS: Good point. I agree it can be difficult sometimes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my questions not attracting answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51076/why-are-my-questions-not-attracting-answers)

Answer (score 17):

As @Saladin says in his comment, patience is a virtue, and getting a problem solved on SO for free is still a privilege, not a right. If you want guaranteed answers, hire somebody.

Also, the two questions you complain about are *way* too broad, and reek of "please debug my incredibly complex jQuery animation thingadongdong, that I copy&pasted from somewhere else, for me". It's little wonder nobody feels a calling to sort these out for you.

Try to split up the question in isolated steps that don't work, and can be illustrated with a small block of code, and put in one clear question each. Those are very likely to get answered much more readily and quickly.

Also, timing is surely also an issue. Weekends are relatively slow on SO. Chances of getting an answer will be best again Monday morning in the U.S. time zones. (A good question will however find an answer regardless whether it's a weekend or not.)

Comment: +1 for "thingadongdong"

Comment: I would change "Chances of getting an answer" to something like "Your chance of getting an answer in the first 10 minutes is higher". Since there are less questions, those that are asked on off-times get more attention. :D

Answer (score 7):

Seriously?
Have you ever thought about the possibility that no one that saw your question was able to answer it? Have you thought about "not posting the same question twice"? (It often stops people from helping spammers). Take a look at your accept rate.. 39% isn't very encouraging to take a serious look into your question. And the quality of your posts as Pekka already mentioned.

Btw I have two unanswered questions, too. Maybe I start a bounty, you can do the same!

Answer (score 6):

**None.**

Impossibility indicates 0% probability. Each time a question gets a view, there is a chance that it will be answered. There are no questions that go over two hours without getting a view. Every view gives the possibility of an answer, views are virtually guaranteed for any question. Therefore, there is no time that it is impossible to get an answer. There is nothing that gives.

Comment: +1 for a very exact answer :)